# How could i import tkinter in python? I am getting a traceback erroe

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

[SIMPLE Tkinter code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buBHz.png)

[Command prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjAvo.png)

I have been trying Tkinter with this basic code. But while running it i am getting an error called Traceback error. I am using Python 3.8.3.

Comment: PL check my code and the error in pics attached above..

Comment: Posting images makes it harder for people to help.  Please post as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

`from tkinter import *`

You capitalized the T in tkinter

Comment: i am using python 3, not python 2

Comment: The python 3 documentation says to use all lower case when importing. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html